# Jquery search working on my desktop device and also on chrome mobile emulator but not working in real MOBILE device(IOS/Android)

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, web, mobile

I have a website which contains jquery search (search based on object properties) and the search result (HTML content) is appended from jquery. it is working perfectly fine on a web device and also on chrome mobile emulator (in dev console) but it is not working on the real device (Tested on both Android and IOS).

say it have an variable x with array of objects `[{name: 'Adithya', value: 'Super Good'}, {name: 'Aparna', value: 'Super Cute'}]`
and when I search for 'adithya' on search - I am getting the result as 'Super Good' and that is getting appended in HTML. When I try to do the same thing on mobile it is not getting appended.
What might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Just got the solution for that.
**This because of 'case sensitive search'
By default, mobile will take the first character of a letter as 'Capital' and in desktop, it will be small.**

The solution is to convert the search value to lower case (toLowerCase() method) and then search on the result value.

```
var searchresult = $('#searchResult').val();
if(searchresult != null || searchresult != ''){
   searchresult = searchresult.toLowerCase();
}
```